# Jenkins and Git integration on local git server

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to set up a jenkins/git server.
I have created an empty repo at `/home/git/repositories/TestProject`, with recursive RW permissions granted to the `jenkins` user.
I am using `file:///home/git/repositories/TestProject` as my GIT URL, but getting this error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/local/bin/git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h file:///home/git/repositories/TestProject HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: '/home/git/repositories/TestProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have also cloned the Elasticsearch Github repo and the same error still shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the command on the commandline yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created an empty repo at /home/git/repositories/TestProject

How?

A `git init /home/git/repositories/TestProject` should create a `.git` folder in the `TestProject` folder, and a `git -C /home/git/repositories/TestProject status` should return a status.

If you don't see a `.git` folder in `/home/git/repositories/TestProject`, that would explain the error message.

The other reason is an access issue.
The [OP Saichovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1579819/saichovsky) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063240/jenkins-and-git-integration-on-local-git-server/34064408#comment55921207_34064408):

> `/home/git` was owned by `root`.
>   Looks like the `jenkins` user ought to have read permissions on all parent (or grandparent) directories.

Comment: I used `git init`. Output for the status command is:

`root@github:/home/git/repositories/TestProject# git -C /home/git/repositories/TestProject status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)`

Manual execution returns exit code of 0 and nothing seems to happen - no messages at all.

Comment: @Saichovsky Does Jenkins execute its job on the same machine where the git repo is created? Does the folder `/home/git/repositories/TestProject/.git` exists?

Comment: Yes. Jenkins and Git are on the same host. The .git directory exists

Comment: @Saichovsky And why use the user 'root'? Are you sure that Jenkins then has the right to read `/home/git/repositories/TestProject`? (and its `.git` subfolder)?

Comment: In my very first post, I did mention that the directories are owned by the `jenkins` user.

Comment: @Saichovsky included the .git subfolder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96956/discussion-between-saichovsky-and-vonc).

Comment: Sorted it out @VonC. /home/git was owned by root. Looks like the jenkins user ought to have read permissions on all parent (or grandparent) directories. Many thanks for your kind assistance though.

Comment: @Saichovsky Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Git expects a "remote" repository (no matter how remote it is) to be a `bare` git repo (created with `git init --bare`, it does not have working copy in it)

You may try to point to `.git` folder inside your repo, but better get yourself a proper set bare one.